# How to stop `/Gm-` being passed to clang_cl.exe from CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, compiler-warnings

I'm building a C++ project on Windows using clang and generating the project using CMake. I'm doing this through Visual Studio/MSBuild. I've installed LLVM and VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset for desktop (x86, x64).

To generate the project and build I do this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -TLLVM-vs2014
cmake --build .
```

When I build I get this warning:

```
clang-cl.exe : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gm-' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

When I print `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` I get:

```
/DWIN32 -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -D_WINDOWS -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-braces
```

But I do not see where `-/Gm` gets inserted or how I can remove it.

Is this something anyone has come across before?

Thanks for your help!

Tom

Comment: I've found that one of the best ways to find where stray compilation flags are coming from is to run cmake with `--trace`. It has a massive output, though, so you'd probably want to send it into a file (I'm not sure on Windows, but it's `cmake ... --trace >out.txt` on Unix))

Comment: Ah good idea! I'll give that a try and see if I can gather any additional information. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a Visual Studio bug - it's early days for them supporting clang.

I think you should do the right thing here and [report this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017).  Microsoft seem to be making a genuine effort to be more open - in both senses of the word - and if we want a good product we should be trying to help them out.

I'll be watching for those downvotes ...

Comment: Hmm interesting! It's good to know it's not just me being a noob :) I'll go ahead and report this and see if I get any more info, I'll report back if I get a reply. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tom `/Gm-` = 'disable minimum rebuild' in the _MSVC_ compiler, that's how I knew it was a bug.

Comment: And thank you for reporting it. What _was_ I thinking?

Comment: No worries! For reference this is a link to the report - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/274954/stop-gm-being-passed-to-clang-clexe-from-cmake.html. I haven't heard anything yet but might get some more insight next week with a bit of luck :)

Comment: Great stuff.  I see they responded 20/6, they're definitely getting it on.